# How to retrieve a value from a Date/Time field

Tags: sql, vb.net

I get an error at `adapter.Fill(dtFuelpriceinfo)`:

> "No value given for required parameters".

TimeOut is a Date/Time field.
But if I replace it with any field with a string data type, it works.

I just don't know how to retrieve its value because it's a Date/Time field.

```
Public Shared Function Check8HourTimeOut(ByVal EmpID As String) As String
    Dim x As String
    Dim dtfuelpriceinfo As New DataTable

    If Not DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        DBConnection.Open()
    Else

    End If

    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TimeOut FROM EmployeeAttendance where " & _
                                          "EmployeeID='" & EmpID & "' order by WorkingDate desc", DBConnection)

    adapter.Fill(dtfuelpriceinfo)
    DBConnection.Close()
    x = dtfuelpriceinfo.Rows(0).Item(0)

    Return x       

End Function
```

Comment: Hurray for SQL Injection!

Comment: Additionally, `What's wrong with my code?` is a terrible title question.  It tells us absolutely nothing about your code issue.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I think the answer to "what's wrong with my code" is that you copied it right out of 2005 / .NET 2.0.  Maybe even 1.1...

Comment: Sql Injection!  Think what would happen if someone passed in `1234'; DROP TABLE EmployeeAttendance; --` as the value of EmpID.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change from "DataTable" type to "DataSet", like so:

```
DIM dtfuelpriceinfo as Dataset
```

and see if you still get the error upon your attempt to fill the DataSet.
If so, then I'd double-check your SQL to be sure it is actually pulling some records.

Another idea: Maybe EmpID is an integer? Your SQL assumes it is a string. You probably know that.

Oh and (the following change may not be necessary because "tables(0)" is probably optional/assumed, but just in case:

```
x = dtfuelpriceinfo.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
```

Apology if I'm way off!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
Public Shared Function Check8HourTimeOut(ByVal EmpID As String) As String

    Try

        Dim x As String = ""
        Dim dtfuelpriceinfo As New DataTable

        If Not DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

            DBConnection.Open()

            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TimeOut FROM EmployeeAttendance where " & _
                                                  "EmployeeID='" & EmpID.Replace("'", "''") & "' order by WorkingDate desc", DBConnection)

            adapter.Fill(dtfuelpriceinfo)

            'Check  if has recored
            If (dtfuelpriceinfo.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                If (Not IsDBNull(dtfuelpriceinfo.Rows(0).Item(0))) Then
                    x = dtfuelpriceinfo.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 'convert date to string representation
                End If
            End If

            DBConnection.Close()

        Else
            'Do something
        End If

        Return x
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: still open to Sql injection.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, Nope! review it carefully. I think you know about escaping?

Comment: But why not spend the few extra _seconds_ it takes to create a parameterized query?  Also, this may still be vulnerable using a technique called Unicode Smuggling.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, Yes you are correct, I may misinterpreted the parameter but I think the `EmployeeID` is coming from an `Integer` value where he/she already cast it into string.  By the way, the guy who asked the question didn't respond so i can't verify the original datatype of the `EmployeeID` and also the reason why i did not removed the single quote enclosure in the value.  If he/she said it is a string/Integral value and it's coming from users input  then a parameterized query technique is at best.